# Is querying a document by ID faster than querying by embedded document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongodb-query, embedded-documents

In my app, I have a User collection and a Board collection. A user document has an embedded participation document, which looks like this: `{_id: 1, board_id: 1, role: "admin"}`.
(A participation is effectively a join between the board and a user)

I am trying to decide how I should get all the user's with participation in a particular board the `board.users` method:

1. Query by embedded participation document: `db.users.find( { 'participation.board_id': board.id }`
2. Maintain a array of user_ids on a board document: `db.users.find( { _id: { $in: board.user_ids } } )`

Assuming the `user.participations.board_id` the field is also indexed, is maintaining a `user_ids` array on board going to result in faster performance?

In essence, Is querying a document by ID faster than querying by an embedded document?

Comment: Depends on the data size and various other details. I suggest focusing on maintainability and readability of your implementation. Keep in mind MongoDB documents cannot exceed 16mb in size.

Comment: I'd suggest going with just the participation on users, or just having it on board. Maintaining the same data in 2 places could lead to discrepancies. To actually answer your question though, the `_id` field is just an indexed field, so there should be no difference.